# Fry frozen chicken

Tags: chicken, frying, frozen

When I planned to fry a chicken, I forgot to get it out of the freezer earlier. I tried to fry it on low heat, so that it can defreeze slowly. Not only is this method really bad for the meat quality, the real issue was that the frozen chicken released its water into the *hot* oil. I think you all can imagine this mess.

So do you have any suggestion how to defreeze it fast or what else I can do in such a situation if I am in a hurry to fry frozen meat?

---

**Update:**

I have already read through the suggested link in the comments, but that does not solve my problem unfortenately. I don't own a microwave and running it under warm water seems to take forever.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the other question already asks for "qucikly". If the quickest method to which you have access is too long for your taste, that's unfortunate, but this is how things are. If somebody has a different answer which has been missed so far, they should be writing it there, and not here, because splitting answers to the same problem into multiple questions just makes this information non-findable for later readers.

Comment: @rumtscho Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest cutting the chicken up before freezing. This should speed up the defrost time. 
Alternatively, the cold water method will take 3-4 hours. [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/food-nutrition/how-to-defrost-chicken-the-safe-way#3) has a nice summary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the thickness of your [chicken](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0956713508002491) or [beef](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1750-3841.2010.02037.x/abstract), a hot-water bath may be a safe option.  However, there are nuances to this, which should be considered, such as how properly you froze the meat in the first place.